# L298N briefly works, then shorts when controlling Nema 17

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I'm trying to control a Nema 17 stepper motor with a L298N H-Bridge.

My wiring is as below (except I'm using a ESP8266 not a YUN, and I have a mains 12V supply rather than batteries). This is consistent with other tutorials I have found online. 
[image]

```
#include <Stepper.h>

const int stepsPerRevolution = 400;  // change this to fit the number of steps per revolution
// for your motor

// initialize the stepper library on pins 8 through 11:
Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, D1, D2, D3, D4);

void setup() {
  // set the speed at 60 rpm:
  myStepper.setSpeed(1);
  // initialize the serial port:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // step one revolution  in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution);
  delay(500);

  // step one revolution in the other direction:
  Serial.println("counterclockwise");
  myStepper.step(-stepsPerRevolution);
  delay(500);
}
```

The issue I am having is that the L298N has it's RED LED on, until I actually try to move the stepper motor. As soon as I try to move it a single step the LED turns off and it takes a while for the board to come back online. I believe this could be an issue with the motor drawing too much current but I have no clue how to fix this.

Cheers in advance!

Comment: what is your question?